# Looking for a rotary engraving machine that supports modern OSes

Tags: macos, manufacturing

I'm looking for a **rotary engraving machine** (with X/Y axis) that does not use laser, and is compatible with modern OSes (mac especially), to engrave designs on wood, metal or plastic.

There was a great machine called the [Dahlgren Wizzard XL](https://laser-engraving-machines.net/not-specified/dahlgren-wizzard-xl-engraver-computerized-engraving-not-roland-vision-gravograph-8164) that I am using here as a reference, but that was a long time ago, these machines are all gone now, and I'm sure that with modern technology there could be something much smaller that one can upload graphic files to, not just text.

I do not want laser engraving, as laser does not produce consistent depth, burns/darkens the materials, smells bad, supports less materials and doesn't get as clean, engraved results as a drill bit tip does.

Cricut and AxiDraw-related answers are not satisfactory, since they do not natively handle rotary carving tools.

Comment: Are you having trouble finding these machines in general? I don't see how something brand new would not support a modern OS. Especially because most of the 3D Printing / CNC / Plotting devices out there all standardize around a few common protocols.

Comment: Yes I can’t find a decent one

Comment: Are you willing to build one? In a brief search I found hardly anything outside of laser engravers (but that may be because we're search with the wrong term for exactly what you want). But there were many DIY designs for plotters/cutters that are relatively simple to build. Finding some good quality software to control a DIY engraver on macOS might be a problem though.

Comment: Yes, you are raising issues I am aware of. There are many amazing machines out there, sometimes hard to find or badly/not advertised outside of their countries of production (I have countless examples). There are [things like this](https://www.ebay.com/itm/265431386489?hash=item3dccf18979%3Ag%3AAMIAAOSwYhlgnisK&nma=true&si=KrhZNd7CI9X5ZJrX4Jitxg8ul44%253D&orig_cvip=true&nordt=true&rt=nc&_trksid=p2047675.l2557) but it's hard knowing what you get for your money, it's not even clear if the needle is a drillbit or just a needle, and hard to tell if there's gonna be any aftersale service at all...